# How to access bundle.js file in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a custom grammar where I have a compiler for and a loader. This loader gets used in my webpack demo app to compile the syntax I have to js.
This generating works well and the output goes to nlweb.bundle.js in the dist folder.
But how do I access this code to actually do something in my html file?

This is my generated file:

```
var nlweblib;
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
/*!*********************************!*\
  !*** ./src/nlweb/working.nlweb ***!
  \*********************************/
let generatorVar;
let generatorLiteral = 20;
function testProcedure(testParameter) {
      let testWaardeProcedure;
      return React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement("h1", null, "Helloworld"), React.createElement("p", null, "Hello"));}
nlweblib = __webpack_exports__;
/******/ })()
;
//# sourceMappingURL=nlweb.bundle.js.map
```

Which comes from here:

```
waarde generatorVar;
waarde generatorLiteral = 20;
procedure testProcedure => testParameter => (
    waarde testWaardeProcedure;
    resultaat => (
    <div>
        <h1>Helloworld</h1>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div> )
);
start testprocedure =>();
```

My webpack config:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/nlweb/working.nlweb',
    output: {
        filename: 'nlweb.bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'nlweblib'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.nlweb$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'nlwebloader'}
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'bundle.css'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/html/index.html'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        port: 9000
    }
}
```

But how do I make this usefull?

Comment: The HTML file should import the JavaScript code. Do you see a `index.html` in `dist`?

Comment: Yes I see the html file in my dist, I can add the bundle.js in my script tag too, But how do I actually use the output of the function you see?

Comment: You have to call `testProcedure`. I have no idea what `waarde` or `nlweblib` is but you have to do it in the code. You can't call `testProcedure` from outside. It's not accessible.